# Multiple maps not working with jqueryMobile, phonegap and google maps

Tags: google-maps, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a mobile app with jQueryMobile alpha 3, latest phonegap and using google maps. Maps are used in three places. First I can change my location. Secondly I can show results of search on map. Finally I can view single result's location on map. When I use them separately - everything works fine. But when I try to check my location and then try to display results on map I receive the following view :

http://images.virtualdesign.pl/images/96594gmap.png

Still finding location of single result works just fine. Also going from the other side - first results on map and then checking my location - result is just the same. Location from the navigator or my search engine is proper, in firebug map looks also initialized properly. Any ideas what might be wrong ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var searchObjects = [],
    searchParameter = 0,
    states = {},
    localization;
    var mobi = $.mobile; 

    function onSuccess(position){
        localization = {'latitude': position.coords.latitude,
                        'longitude': position.coords.longitude };
        mobi.pageLoading(true);
        mobi.changePage('map.htm');
        return false;     
    }

    function onError(error) {
        mobi.pageLoading(true);
        alert('Unable to get location.');
    }  

    $('.page-link').live("click", function() {
        if (!!navigator.geolocation){
            mobi.pageLoading(false);
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
        }
    });

    $('.page-map').live("pagecreate", function() {
        if(localization){
            initialize(localization.latitude, localization.longitude, 0);
        }         
    });

    $('.page-map-results').live("pagecreate", function() {
        initializeResults(searchObjects);
    });

    function initialize(lat,lng, loc){      
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map1, myOptions,marker;

        myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map1
        });

        if(!loc){
            map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
        }
        else{
            map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_localization"),myOptions);
        } 

        marker.setMap(map1);
        return map1;
    }

    function initializeResults(data_map){

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.961869,19.134521);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };              
        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"),myOptions);

        var icon1,     
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
        maxlng = 0,
        maxlat = 0,
        minlng = 0,
        minlat = 0,
        positions = 0;

        icon1 = 'images/map_icon.png';     

        for(var i=0; i < data_map.length; i++){
            var pos_lat = parseFloat(data_map[i]['lat']);
            var pos_lon = parseFloat(data_map[i]['lon']);
            if(!isNaN(pos_lat) && !isNaN(pos_lon)){               
                positions = 1;
                addMarker(pos_lat, pos_lon, icon1);
                if(pos_lat < minlat || minlat==0){ 
                    minlat = pos_lat
                }
                if(pos_lat > maxlat || maxlat==0){ 
                    maxlat = pos_lat
                }
                if(pos_lon < minlng || minlng==0){
                    minlng = pos_lon
                }
                if(pos_lon > maxlng || maxlng==0){
                    maxlng = pos_lon
                }
                lat = minlat + (( maxlat - minlat)/2);
                lng = minlng + (( maxlng - minlng)/2);
                var allpoints = new google.maps.LatLng(pos_lat, pos_lon);
                bounds.extend(allpoints);
            }
        }     

        if(positions){
            map2.fitBounds(bounds);         
        }

        function addMarker(lat, lon, icon){
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map2,
                icon: icon
            });            
            marker.setMap(map2);
        }
        return map2;
    }    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">  </script>
```

And templates for both maps :

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" class="page-map" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Gdzie jestem</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding:0;"> 
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" class="page-map-results" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <div data-role="header" class="header"><h1>Wyniki</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding:0;"> 
        <div id="map_canvas2" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just a quick walkthrough through the code - `page-map` is the localization map initialized with `page-link`. `page-map-results` is the second template for displaying results. If `initialize` gets `loc` parameter it shows the third map - localization of single result.

Comment: using : google.maps.event.trigger(map2, 'resize'); from the console seems to solve the problem but the zoomin as well as center is completely broken. Also including this in my code doesn't change anything.

Comment: wrapping the code in 'pageshow' event shows the map with proper size but centering and zoomin is still broken.

Comment: solved. Storing the calculated zoom, center and bounds and then setting them once again on 'pageshow' did the job.